# What is Issuer secret?? What should be its input.?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using PersistentQueueListener from SDK to receive messages from Service Bus. While I run the PersistentQueueListener Project it expects few imputs like

1. Service NameSpace
2. Issuer name
3. Issuer secret.

I don't have a clue of Issuer secret here. and what should be given here. I know the issuer name from "developer resources" in CRM application.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

[Answer](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/knowledge-base/cache-invalidation-acs/)

Issuer Secret
The key for your Service Bus namespace connection. Generally, you should use the Default Key for your namespace.